# Prestashop large feed import browser timeout

Tags: browser, import, timeout, prestashop, feed

I am developing a prestashop module for an xml feed import, the problem I get is when the file is large, the loop get long and the browser times out. Just to let you know, I have increase many values like set_time_limit, max_execution_time  in php.ini, but it didn’t work.

Please give a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In virtualmin > Server Configuration > website options and increase “Maximum php script run time” worked for me. 
But what places it made changes still not clear to me, because I increase execution time in php.ini manually and it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

If you import products,did you try to turn off Indexation in Preferences -> Search ?